# Why generic overload results ambiguous?

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I wondering why the generic overloading is not allowed, and it results in a compiler error of "ambiguous" resolution.

Here is the sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();

        p.DoWork(new First());
        p.DoWork(new Second());
        p.DoWork(new Multi());    //ambiguous: that's right!

        p.Test<IFirst>(new First());  //ambiguous???
    }


    private void DoWork(IFirst arg) { }

    private void DoWork(ISecond arg) { }

    private void Test<T>(T arg) where T : IFirst { }

    private void Test<T>(T arg) where T : ISecond { }
}


interface IFirst { }

interface ISecond { }

class First : IFirst { }

class Second : ISecond { }

class Multi : IFirst, ISecond { }
```

I am not able to feel the difference between the explicit form (DoWork) and the generic one, having explicitly declared the interface to consider. Why the first one is allowed and the second does not?

My goal is having two "Test" methods behaving similarly, but not exactly.

Any workaround (other than naming the methods differently)?

Thank you everybody in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Constraints are not part of the signature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx).

Comment: Okay. The article explains the limitations, although I'm making an effort to understand *why* cannot be solved.
However, from my sample viewpoint, it looks strange indeed: the compiler should not have any problem resolving the right method if only "tried" to consider the generic.
It looks much more a compiler limitation, than a unsolvable problem. Of sure not a bug.

Comment: @Mario: It would certainly be possible to solve this. It was a design decision, to implement it like this.

Answer (score 0):

This code will not compile even without making any calls to the methods at all. The problem here is that since generic type constraints are not part of the methods' signatures, the two `Test<T>` declarations have the same signature:

```
private void Test<T>(T arg) where T : IFirst { }

private void Test<T>(T arg) where T : ISecond { }
```

This will not compile for the same reason that the following would also not compile:

```
private void Foo() { }

private void Foo() { }
```

The compiler will complain that a method with the same signature has already been declared.

Notice that the `DoWork` methods do not have this problem:

```
private void DoWork(IFirst arg) { }

private void DoWork(ISecond arg) { }
```

Since parameter types *are* part of the method signature, here we are talking about two standard overloads of one method, which is perfectly OK.